# How to combine several sequences contained different types of elements into one sequence in clojure

Tags: clojure

I am wondering how to combine two or more different sequences with different types of elements into one list. Like:

```
(defn combine [vector]
   (conj '(remove number? vector) 10))
```

Here is a test:

```
(combine [1 2 d g f e ])
```

This is the error:

```
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: d in this context,
```

I want to know can use "conj, concat, into" these functions to combine them. Also, I have add quote in front of the list (d g f e), but the error says d cannot be solved. Is anyone help me to figure out this problem? Thank you so much!

Comment: Your test doesn't "combine two or more different sequences".  Please describe your input and desired output more clearly.

Comment: A more usual (than quoting) way when just testing is to use keywords, so you would have `:d :g :f :e`, and avoid troubles altogether.

Answer (score 3):

quote the input to the function to prevent it from resolving the symbols in the list:

```
(combine '[1 2 d g f e ])
```

the `'` is a shortcur (reader macro) for the `quote` function. otherwise it will attempt to trnslate (called "evaluation" in Clojure-speak) the symbols in the vector before it passes the vector to the `combine` function. with the `'` it will try to look up a var in the current namespace names `d` and get it's value in order to put it into the vector.

Comment: `(defn sum [vector]
 (reduce + (filter number? vector)))
 
(defn replace-with-sum [vector]
 (conj (remove number? vector)) (sum vector))`    Thank you for your help. For this new code, when I test `(replace-with-sum '[1 2 d g e 4])` why it yield `13` instead of `(d g e 7)` Thank you!

Comment: closing ) in the second expression is in the wrong place in that example, you may like it better as:(defn replace-with-sum [vector] (conj (remove number? vector) (sum vector)))

Comment: oh! yeah! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The quote is in the wrong place. Try

```
(defn combine [vector]
   (conj (remove number? vector) 10))

(combine '(1 2 d g f e)) 
;(10 d g f e)
```